# MVC, display a list of images asynchronously with AJAX / JQUERY

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax

I have a site, where I load a list of images (thumbnails) from the database. The problem is that the images are displayed rather slowly, as fetching each thumbnail with Url.Action is rather time-consuming (when going through the whole MVC pipeline).

Therefore, I would like to load the images asynchronously with Ajax & JQUERY, while displaying the standard loading image (ajaxloag.info) for each image, until the image is loaded. A similar question has been raised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346739/asp-net-mvc-how-do-i-load-an-image-asynchronously), but I need a more complete example, as I am very new to MVC and JQUERY.

Thanks in advance,

**View (partialView)**

```
// Foreach product, display the corresponding thumbnail
<% foreach (var p in Model)
   { %>
.
.

    <img width="100" src="<%= Url.Action( "Thumbnail", "Products", new { productId = p.ID } ) %>" alt=""  />
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Thumbnail(string productId)
        {
            try
            {
                Guid pid = new Guid(productId);
                byte[] thumbnailData = _productsRepository.GetProductThumbnail(pid);
                if (thumbnailData != null)
                {
                    return File(thumbnailData, "image/jpg");
                }
                else
                {
                    return File(@"../Content/missingproduct.png", "image/jpg");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw e;
            }
        }
```

**UPDATE - The parent view containing the Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() 
    {
       getContentTab (1);
    });

    function getContentTab(index)
     {
        var criteria = {
            categoryId : "<%: ViewBag.Header %>", 
            tabIndex: index, 
            searchString : "<%: ViewBag.SearchString %>"
            };
        var url='<%= Url.Content("~/Products/GetAjaxTab") %>'
        var targetDiv = "#listContent"; 
        var ajaxLoadUrl = '<%: Url.Content("/Content") %>/ajax-loader.gif';
        var ajaxLoading = "<img id='ajax-loader' src='" + ajaxLoadUrl + "' align='left' height='28' width='28' />";


        $(targetDiv).html("<div>" + ajaxLoading + " Loading...</div>");

tag in respect to the callback. 
        $.get(url, criteria, function(result)
        {
            $(targetDiv).html(result);
        });

    }


    function AjaxStart()
    {
        $('#listContent').mask('Opdaterer');
    }

    function AjaxEnd()
    {
        $('#listContent').unmask();

    }

    $(function () {
        $('.async').load(function () {
            $(this).unbind('load');
            this.src = $(this).attr('data-img-url');
            alert('2');
        });
    });

//]]>


</script>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use HTML5 `data-*` attributes:

```
<img width="100" 
     src="ajax-loader.gif" 
     class="async" 
     data-img-url="<%= Url.Action("Thumbnail", "Products", new { productId = p.ID }) %>" 
/>
```

and then in a separate js file:

```
$(function() {
    $('.async').load(function() {
        $(this).unbind('load');
        this.src = $(this).attr('data-img-url');
    });
});
```

Also I would use editor/display templates instead of writing `foreach` loops in the views:

```
<%= Html.DisplayForModel() %>
```

and in the corresponding display template you would put the image:

```
<%@ Control 
    Language="C#" 
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<AppName.Models.Product>" 
%>
<img width="100" 
     src="ajax-loader.gif" 
     class="async" 
     data-img-url="<%= Url.Action("Thumbnail", "Products", new { productId = Model.ID }) %>" 
/>
```

Comment: +1 good answer. Any reason you are waiting for the ajax loader image to `load` before setting the new url?

Comment: @Josiah Ruddell, leave the user the chance to see a spinner image while loading the actual one.

Comment: @Darin, I can't really get it to work. It doesnt hit my action on the specified controller. Is there something missing in your example? :)

Comment: @Nima, what does FireBug say? Can you see the request for the image being sent? Did you include jquery in your page? Do you enter the `.load` javascript callback?

Comment: @Darin, no, I can't see the request being sent, so I must be missing out something. Actually, the view snippet above, is in the PartialView, so the Javascript function is so far copied to the parent view (the one initiating the partialView). I am using JQUERY to load the list of products, so i think JQUERY is included correctly. How can I make sure that the .load javascript callback is entered? (I am very newb to this JQUERY stuff)

Comment: @Nima, try putting an `alert` inside it and see if it is executed.

Comment: @Darin, I have tried the following, and it doesnt execute the alert.

        $(function () {
            $('.async').load(function () {
                alert('1');
                $(this).unbind('load');
                this.src = $(this).attr('data-img-url');
                alert('2');
            });
        });

Comment: @Nima, yeap there is a problem. Did you put the `class="async"` to your images? Does the `ajax-loader.gif` exist on your server? Make sure it exists and you could also reference it like this: `src="<%= Url.Content("~/images/ajax-loader.gif") %>"`

Comment: @Darin, the class is there as you wrote in your snippet. Currently, the following is present in my view: 

`<img width="100" alt="" src="../../Content/paging-loading.gif"  class="async" data-img-url="<%= Url.Action("Thumbnail", "Products", new { productId = p.ID }) %>" />`   The GIF (loader) image is shown for each image in the list.

Comment: @Nima and @Darin - if you are loading the view w ajax, the image init function is running onload (`$(function() {`) you will need to activate after the ajax load complete.

Comment: @Josiah Ruddell, personally I am not loading anything, I am drinking my beer at the moment :-)

Comment: @Darin - that sound good.. beer 4:00. I tried, "he", didn't work, so i went with "you" :p

Comment: @Josia Ruddell, good point! That might be the problem! 
@Darin, good point. Maybe I should consider that instead :)

Comment: @Nima, LOL, you definitely should consider this. Drink a [Maß of beer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67008/are-rumors-of-a-film-true-i-hope-so-by-golly/67021#67021) and you will see how all problems get solved :-)

Comment: @Nima, now that you have updated your question, @Josia Ruddell remark is true. You are loading the partial through AJAX. So all you need to do is put my code (the stuff with `$('.async').load(...`) inside the `$.get` success callback, just after the `$(targetDiv).html(result);` call.

Comment: @Josiah Ruddell, never changing this avatar :-)

Comment: @Darin and @Josiah: Guys, it WORKS NOW! Thank you so much! Next beer is on me :)

Comment: @Darin, it was VERY helpful. Actually, my next question would be to ask if there is another way of loading the images instead of using  Url.Action. The thing is, that loading the images is still a time-consuming task, as the requests are going through the standard MVC pipeline. Isn't there are way to just call the action on the controller like the javascript get shown in the question. $.get(url,...etc...? Or is the current way I am doing it, the right way to do it?

Comment: @Nima, it looks like those images are dynamically generated by your controller action, so, no, there isn't a better way than using `Url.Action` and pointing to the corresponding action.

Comment: @Darin, Thank you very much for your great answers. Much appreciated! Have a wonderful day!